# How to store only limited number of doc in elasticsearch.

Tags: elasticsearch, go, elasticsearch-5

I need to store only say 10 number docs under a particular index. And the 11th item should replace the old item i.e 1st item. So that i will be having only 10 doc at any time.
I am using elacticsearch in golang

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store only 10 doc then
    you should apply algo = (document no%10)+1.
    the return value is your elasticsearch _id field
    the algo retyrn only 1 to 10. and always index it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you will have fixed names for documents, like 1, 2,...,10 or whatever. So one approach could be to use Redis to implement a circular list https://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush#pattern-circular-list (you can also implement your own algorithm to implement that circular list by code)

So basically you should follow the next steps:

- You load those 10 values ordered in the circular list, let's say 1,2, 3, ... 10
- When you want to store a document in Redis, you extract an element from the list, for our list that element will be `1`
- make a query count on your ElasticSearch index to get the number of the document in the index
- if you get a count < 10 you call insert document query with your data and with the number extracted from the list as the document name. If count = 10 you call update document query on ElasticSearch

  The circular will progress in this way:
- The initial state of the list is `[1, 2, ...10]`. You extract `1` and after extracting it, it goes to the end of the list: `[2,3,..., 10,1]`
- Second extraction from the list, current state of the list: `[2, 3, ...10, 1]`. You extract `2` and after extracting it, it goes to the end of the list: `[3,4,..., 1,2]`
- and so on

Comment: Adding Redis just for this seems totally unnecessary. That's a lot of development and operational overhead for what is very simple to implement with no new dependencies.